# Why does this function only replace the substring "model" in the string "tempstring" once?

Tags: excel, vba

So I've created this function to replace a substring in a string based on a variable "model" that is set at certain points in my code but when I run it the substring is only replaced for the first value of "model" and when "model" gets a new value the function doesn't replace the substring anymore. Below is the code please let me know if more context is needeed.

```
Function Scrape()

' (1) Copy and paste desired model years from autoevolution.com into column "A" of the CopyPasting worksheet without formatting
    Dim lastrow As Long, model As String, tempstring As String
    Dim i As Integer, icount As Integer
    
    Sheets("CopyPasting").Select

    ' model = Range("A1").Value
    
    lastrow = 30000
    For i = 1 To lastrow
    
        ' Search each line of the paste for substrings that we don't want to remove them
        If InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase("photo gallery")) > 0 Or Len(Range("A" & i)) > 125 Or InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase("review & photos")) > 0 Then
     
            Range("A" & i) = ""
        
        ' Trying out the new filters
        
        ' Search for the name of the model using the make
        ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase(Range("M2"))) > 0 And InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase("HP")) = 0 Then
              
            icount = icount + 2
            Range("H" & icount + 1) = Range("A" & i).Value
            Range("H" & icount) = vbNewLine
            model = Range("A" & i).Value
            
        ' Find the type of engine and then activate the "engines" variable in order to capture all engines in the group
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(Range("A" & i)), "engine") > 0 Or InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase("electric")) > 0 Then
            
            icount = icount + 1
            Range("H" & icount) = Range("A" & i).Value
            
        ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase("HP")) > 0 Then
    
            icount = icount + 1
            tempstring = Range("A" & i).Value
            tempstring = Replace(tempstring, model, "", 1, 100)
            Range("H" & icount) = tempstring
          
            
        
        ' Add the production years to the model name
        ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(Range("A" & i)), LCase(20)) > 0 Then
      
            icount = icount + 1
            Range("H" & icount) = Range("H" & icount).Value & " : " & Range("A" & i).Value
    
        End If
    
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I cannot easily follow the logic of your code. Inside the loop you are using the following structure: `If - code - ElseIf - code - ElseIf - code - ElseIf - code - ElseIf - code - End If`. So only one code is run in each loop. `model = ...` and `Replace` are not in the same `code`. So they can never run both in the same loop. This may be the reason why the result is not as expected.

Comment: A remark to `Replace`: Your code doesn't replace anything. It just deletes `model` in `tempstring`. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008930);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) for the `Replace` function.

Comment: Hi @Stringeater, I am trying to remove the `model` from `tempstring` not trying to replace it with something else. Also, since I am setting the `model` variable in a different loop than I am referencing it as they are in different cells that shouldn't matter. Basically it is referencing the `model` variable in every loop and does update the variable correctly but `Replace` is not finding '''model''' in `tempstring` any other time after the first set. I think I will clean up my code and post it new since I realize the comments are outdated as well.

Comment: Do you know how to step through the code in debug mode? You can set a breakpoint in the first line of the For loop (press F9) and go there by pressing F5. Then you can move in single steps with F8. You can mark a variable and put it to the watch window with Shift-F9. Like this you can watch `model` and `tempstring` or range values. This way you should be able to find the problem.